# Visualizing decision tree using spark_tree_plotting package

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, decision-tree, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to use spark-tree-plotting package to visualize the decision tree. In the this link https://github.com/julioasotodv/spark-tree-plotting , they have explained two methods to install. By changing the conf file nothing seems to happen.
For the installation through second method i am giving the command in cmd- spark-submit --packages julioasotodv:spark-tree-plotting:0.2 %C:\Users\pallaw\PycharmProjects\decision tree\case_1\dt2.py%

but i am getting the error: cannot load the main class from JAR file:/C:/spark/bin/%25C:/Users/Pallaw/PycharmProjects/decision.

I am new to all this, please if anyone has idea, help me to solve this.

Comment: any updates on this one ? :)

Comment: @Matthew I could not visualize using this method. what worked for me was databricks. i signed in as a community edition user. Python doesn't work there too. Using scala can help you in visualizing the tree but it does not gives any information on the gini value of each node.

Comment: I have been trying to fiddle with this package for a while to make it work but I guess even the creator of the package on github stopped committing to it.

Comment: @Matthew hopefully you got something solved!